# How to receive the RealityCapture results on an email address

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-realitycapture

I would like to automate the sending of the results (.obj, orthophoto) on my email address and not have to wait for the processing to finish to start the downloading.

I uploaded my images on the Photoscene and I launched the processing successfully.
Furthermore, I added into the Photoscene parameter callback "email://myadress@mail.com".
To summarize, I implemented the "[Create 3D Mesh from Photos](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/reality-capture/v1/tutorials/create-3d-mesh-from-photos/)" tutorial without the last 2 steps.

However, I still haven't received anything until now to my email address.
So, I am wondering if there is an additional step I am missing to get my result automatically or more generally if it is even possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is a bit misleading. The email will only be sent to the user associated with the project instead of any arbitrary email address.

If the project was created with 2-legged auth, this will be the Forge developer.
if the project was created with 3-legged auth, this will be the email of user who authorized.

Specifying

> callback=email://

without any email address is sufficient.

However, a user must also be opted-in for electronic communications on the https://profile.autodesk.com/settings portal.